# How do I extend django's createsuperuser management command?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.1

I extended my user model by adding a mandatory `Company` field, so that every user belongs to some company. The `Company` field is a foreign key to another model that defines what a company is.

This works great, except for the fact that `./manage createsuperuser` broke, since it doesn't know to add this custom mandatory field.

Turns out that I can add `REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['company']` to my custom user model, which will tell `createsuperuser` to ask for this field. That's better, but since the company field is a Foreign Key, it asks for an ID of the company, which has to be looked up by anyone using the `createsuperuser` command - not exactly user friendly. I want all admins created with the `createsuperuser` command to belong to the same company, and for that company to be created automatically if it doesn't exist.

Reading django's [documentation on createsuperuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser), it mentions the exact thing I want to do, and the exact reason I want to do it:

> You can subclass the management command and override get_input_data()
>   if you want to customize data input and validation. Consult the source
>   code for details on the existing implementation and the method’s
>   parameters. For example, it could be useful if you have a ForeignKey
>   in REQUIRED_FIELDS and want to allow creating an instance instead of
>   entering the primary key of an existing instance.

I'm just not sure where in my project I should be overriding the get_input_data() method.

Edit:

The way I extended the user model is by adding this to models.py of one of my apps (login_app):

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
```

and adding this to settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'login_app.User'
```

Comment: DO you use Custom auth model or django default auth model?

Comment: Not sure. I added some more details about how I extended my user model. Does that mean I'm using a custom auth model? I'm still using a username and password to authenticate, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom command, see Django's related documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/). 
Try something like below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.management.commands import createsuperuser

class Command(createsuperuser.Command):
    def get_input_data(self, field, message, default=None):
        """
        Override this method if you want to customize data inputs or
        validation exceptions.
        """
        raw_value = input(message)
        if default and raw_value == '':
            raw_value = default
        try:
            val = field.clean(raw_value, None)
        except exceptions.ValidationError as e:
            # here you FK code 

        return val
```